# Matrix Operation--

Tags: matrices

If I have a vector $\begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3\end{bmatrix} $ and a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 & 1 \\ 5 & -4 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 8\end{bmatrix}.$ How can we reconstruct the vector and matrix such that I can obtain the follow form:
$\begin{bmatrix}-2a_1 & 0 & 1a_1 \\ 5a_2 & -4a_2 & 2a_2 \\ 3a_3 & 1a_3 & 8a_3\end{bmatrix}.$

Comment: It is just the product of the vector and the matrix

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerProduct.html

Answer (score 1):

To construct a $3\times 3$ matrix, you can use two such ones. One idea to reach your goal may be:
$$\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & a_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a_3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 0 & 1 \\ 5 & -4 & 2 \\ 3 & 1 & 8\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2a_1 & 0 & 1a_1 \\ 5a_2 & -4a_2 & 2a_2 \\ 3a_3 & 1a_3 & 8a_3\end{bmatrix}.$$